# How can I create template of complex<double> type in vector<T>?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a datastructure using classes as shown below but I am having a problem with template implementation as the type is actually of complex. Sry I am not using the right terminology but the code of classes shown below:

```
template<class T>
 class tableType
    {
      public:
      string key;
      vector<T> setValue;
      ~tableType();
      tableType operator = (const tableType& obj) {
      this->key = obj.key;
      this->setValue = obj.setValue;
      }
   };


 template<class typechosen>
  class dataContainer :public tableType {
    public:
    vector<tableType<double>> ordNts;
    vector<tableType<typechosen>> fields;
    string type;
   ~dataContainer();
   dataContainer operator = (const dataContainer& obj) {
    this->ordNts = obj.ordNts;
    }
 };
```

For example sample data type when I create a class variable it should be of format

```
dataContainer<complex<double>> dataStore;
dataStore.ordNts; //will be of type vector<tableType<double>>
dataStore.fields; //will be of type vector<tableType<complex<double>>>
```

How can I achieve this type of template?

Comment: Get rid of the `vector<>` in `vector<tableType<double>> ordNts;
    vector<tableType<typechosen>> fields` if you don't want those members to be vectors

Comment: I want them to be vector<vector<T>> for reading my tabular data @NathanOliver

Comment: You might want to adjust your question then.  Your comment says *will be of type tableType<complex<double>>*, not `vectctor<tableType<complex<double>>>`

Comment: Yes sry I rectified it

Comment: Okay, your class does this so it's unclear to me what your issue is.

Comment: so when I create a variable like this dataContainer<complex<double>> dataStore; it throws an error of creation as complex is not a type name

Comment: Did you `#include <complex>`?  Also, `complex` is inside the standard namespace so you need to use `std::complex` unless you have a `using namespace std;` or `using std::complex` in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215335/discussion-between-pod-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: @NathanOliver the class as posted doesn't specify a template parameter for the base class of dataContainer.  Probably there should not even be a base class

Comment: Oh wow.  I completely missed `dataContainer` was inheriting from `tableType`.  I agree that most likely that should not be there

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template<class T>
class tableType
{
public:
    std::string key;
    std::vector<T> setValue;
};

template<class T>
class dataContainer
{
public:
    std::vector<tableType<double>> ordNts;
    std::vector<tableType<T>> fields;
    std::string type;
};

int main()
{
    dataContainer<std::complex<double>> dataStore;
    auto j = dataStore.fields;
}
```

The `dataContainer` should not have a base class (well, not based on the requirements you have posted so far anyway).

Also check you are compiling in C++11 or later mode  (the use of `>>` token to terminate two templates was added in C++11).

If you are still having trouble then please edit the question to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As speculated in comments, perhaps you missed out some includes or `std::` in the real code, or something.

NB. Classes have an implicitly generated `operator=` so you should not write your own unless you need different behaviour, which this class should not , see [Rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Similarly you probably should not define your own destructor. Keeping the code as simple as possible reduces the chance of mistakes and makes it easier to review the code for correctness.